# Batch file to report the filename of the first file in a directory, in a message

Tags: batch-file, filenames, swap

I'm setting up a rudimentary directory swap that I plan on using to flip between vanilla and modified versions of Grand Theft Auto V.  What I'm shooting for is a batch file that will name-swap the two directories, then tell me via message box which installation variant is in the primary directory. So far, I have a swapper that at least tells me the swap succeeded.

```
@echo off
ren "Grand Theft Auto V" "Grand Theft Auto V_swap"
ren "Grand Theft Auto V_mod" "Grand Theft Auto V"
ren "Grand Theft Auto V_swap" "Grand Theft Auto V_mod"
msg "%username%" "Files successfully swapped!"
```

I have added a file in each root dir `vanilla.txt` and `modified.txt`, but I don't know how to go any further to use either of their names to the message.

How can I have the message report the name of the text file in the primary directory?  Bonus points if you can tell me an easier method.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I, ah, never said anything about a "first line," but I _am_ asking how I can have a message tell me what the name of the _**first file**_ in a folder is.  Also, the swap rotates out, as, if I ran the batch once, it would swap the contents of "Grand Theft Auto V" and "Grand Theft Auto V_mod," but if I did it a second time the files would be as they originally were.

Comment: Pretty much what you said.  I just want it to say either "vanilla" or "modified."

Comment: And let's cleanup comments here please. I will edit your answer to make it 100% clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just need run a for loop, assuming that those are the only txt files per directory root:

```
@echo off
ren "Grand Theft Auto V" "Grand Theft Auto V_swap"
ren "Grand Theft Auto V_mod" "Grand Theft Auto V"
ren "Grand Theft Auto V_swap" "Grand Theft Auto V_mod"
for %%i in ("Grand Theft Auto V\*.txt") do msg %username% %%~ni
```

If however you have other text files in the directory, we can either test their name or instead rename your files to some extension not anywhere else. i.e `vanilla.ren` and `modified.ren` then simply do:

To test the names and only msg when the name match:

```
for %%i in ("Grand Theft Auto V\*.txt") do (
    if /i "%%~ni"=="vanilla" msg %username% %%~ni
    if /i "%%~ni"=="modified" msg %username% %%~ni
)
```

or dummy extension:

```
for %%i in ("Grand Theft Auto V\*.ren") do msg %username% %%~ni
```

Comment: While there are other .txt items in the modified installation, I can easily just replace the file extension with some other bogus extension, as the !*.txt files themselves are empty and are only used for their filenames.  This will do!

Comment: yes, it is better to give a dummy extension, o we can even test the filename, so I will update anwer.